# Rails 3 and JQuery Mobile - Custom delete dialog issues

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to incorporate JQuery Mobile with Rails 3 and I have a **contact model** and a **contacts controller**.

JQuery Mobile has the ability to create a dialog out of a normal view that works well for mobile devices.  I'm trying to take advantage of this while deleting data from my model.  Instead of the usual, "Are you sure?" javascript popup, I have created a **delete.html.erb** view and a **delete method** in the controller.

**The problem is, when the JQuery Mobile dialog is displayed, it acts on the 'Update' action instead of the 'Destroy' action.** (see images below)

I'm using this to render the delete view:

```
# GET /contacts/1  
  def delete
    @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
    render 'delete'     
  end
```

Here is the destroy method:

```
def destroy
    contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
    contact.destroy    
 end
```

And here is the code for the delete view:

```
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Delete</h1>     
</div>


<div data-role="content">   
    <%= form_for(@contact, { :action => 'destroy', :id => @contact }) do %>     
        <%= "Delete #{@contact.first_name} #{@contact.last_name}?" %>       
        <%= submit_tag  %>  
    <% end %>   
</div>
```

Which causes this to render:
[image]

I ***think*** the solution to the problem lies in the address bar here:
[image]

As you can see, the submit button text is being auto-populated by the update method.  The delete view is being attached to the edit view, and Rails is treating it as an update instead of a destroy.

My **routes.rb** file is very simple:

```
resources :contacts
```

I'm assuming something would need to change in here, but I'm not sure what.  And/or something may need to change in respect to the use of JQuery Mobile.

**Any help is greatly appreciated!**

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is just a guess, but it looks like it is trying to load it via ajax. Try disabling ajax with `data-ajax="false"`. It may also be the case that you are on an old version of jqm. I know older versions change pages via hash while new versions use push state unless you disable it.

If you are trying to delete the user using ajax perhaps it'd be best to use a vclick event handler on the button and said a manual ajax request.